# Problem understanding explicit constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

After reading this thread
[What does the explicit keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

I made up this program

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
  explicit MyClass(int a)
  {
    cout<<"Int was called"<<endl;
    val = a;
  }

  MyClass(char *a)
  {
    cout<<"Char was called"<<endl;
    val = atoi(a);
  }

  MyClass(const MyClass& copy)
  {
    cout<<"Copy Const was called"<<endl;
    this->val = copy.val;
  }

  inline const int getval() const
  { return val; }

  private:
  int val ;
};
```

main code

```
int main()
{
  int x=4;
  char y='4';
  char *z = &y;

  MyClass a(x);
  MyClass b(z);
  MyClass c(a);
  MyClass d('4');

  cout<<a.getval()<<endl;
  cout<<b.getval()<<endl;
  cout<<c.getval()<<endl;
  cout<<d.getval()<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
Int was called
Char was called
Copy Const was called
Int was called
4
4
4
52
```

Now, as per thread above, it should throw error after the constructor call on object d but it didn't.

g++ version info

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)
```

I am not sure if i have done something wrong in the above code.
Please help

Comment: Why did you expect an error in while constructing `d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicit constructor will not allow you to do something like "implicit conversion", e.g. when initializing an object:

```
MyClass d = 4;
```

or when calling a function with parameters:

```
void foo( const MyClass& param);

... 

foo( 4);
```

In your case, there is a conversion from char to int before calling the explicit constructor, which is as designed.

Comment: Also there is no point in returning 'const int' from operator 'int' as cv qualified rvalues of fundamental types do not make sense. Am I right?

Comment: A result by value is returned, so I see no point for const int.

Comment: I never do it, but I have read some authors recommending it to avoid mistakenly changing the temporary in situations like `if ( foo() = 0 )` (when `==` was intended). For most such situations current compilers can be set to produce warnings so I have never really used it.

Comment: That's why you could rephrase in a form some people hate: if( 0 == foo())

Answer (score 1):

Actually, constructing `d` was done with the `int` constructor. Your `char` (`'4'`) was implicitly casted to an `int`. This is legal in C/C++ since these are both integer numbers, with `int` being at least as wide as `char` (the other way round needs an explicit cast, as possible precision loss can result).

The output for object `d` was the ASCII code for the character "4".

Answer (score 1):

The `explicit` keyword defines that the constructor is not available for implicit conversions, but in your code you are explicitly requesting the construction of the objects from the values.

If you change the code to:

```
MyClass d = 'a';
MyClass x = 5;
```

Then the conversion is implicit and you will get an error.

Note that the conversion that is important is not from `'a'` to `int` but from `int` to `MyClass`. The compiler is allowed to perform the conversion from `'a'` to `int`, as the `MyClass(int)` constructor is explicitly requested in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

'4' is a char, which is freely convertible to int. 52 is the character code for '4'

Answer (score 0):

A "char" (as in 'd') has an int value in C++. Infact, 52 is the integer ASCII value of 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error - it just invokes your int constructor with the integer value '4', which is actually U+0034 (Hex) or the number 52. All char constants in C/C++ are stored as int internally

Answer (score 0):

Any `char` literal is an `int`, you can say `int i = 'a`;`